# Get distribution function equation from single particle equation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, statistics, accelerator-physics

Suppose we have a large set of particles, and we know, that some parameter $x$ of each particle satisfies the following equation:

$\dfrac{dx_i}{dt}=f(x_i)$.

Our set of particles can be described with particle distribution function $\Psi(x, t)=dN/dx$, which gives the number of particles with parameter in range ($x, x+dx)$, so total number of particles $N$ is

$N=\int\Psi(x,t)dx$

Suppose for certainty the distribution is similar to normal distribution.
How one can derive the corresponding equation for the distribution function:

$\dfrac{\partial\Psi(x, t)}{\partial t}=?$

Comment: What is $N$ anyway?

Comment: I think you are interested in the total derivative $d\psi(x,t) /dt $ and not the partial one, am I wrong?

Comment: @mas - I've made an edit to explain it better

Comment: @DelCrosB I'm mainly interested in partial derivative, since the idea is to get the pdf equation (like Fokker-Planck or Schrödinger equation) from single particle equation. But if you can derive full derivative - that would also be awesome.

Comment: The fully deterministic evolution of the phase space is given by the Liouville equation. But good luck solving that for anything not trivial!